# error when running ./configure installing Kerberos v5

Tags: gcc, kerberos, ubuntu-18.04

i'm trying to install kerberos on ubuntu 18.04. as the manual in [this link](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.3/krb5-1.3.6/doc/krb5-install.html#Building%20Within%20a%20Single%20Tree) said the steps are:

1. cd /u1/krb5-1.3/src
2. ./configure
3. make

when i run *./configuration* it checks some dependencies but cant find **res_search**

these are logs on my terminal:

```
configure: creating cache ./config.cache
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for gcc option to accept ANSI C... none needed
Looking for ././config
configure: adding extra warning flags for gcc
built in krb4 support
checking which version of com_err to use... krb5
checking which version of subsystem package to use... krb5
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for gethostbyname... yes
checking for socket... yes
checking if DNS Kerberos lookup support should be compiled in... yes
checking for res_search... no
checking for res_search in -lresolv... no
configure: error: Cannot find resolver support routine res_search in -lresolv.
```

two last lines are what makes this command fail.

what should i do?

thanks.

Comment: That document is very old. Why don't you just install the Kerberos packages from Ubuntu (https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/kerberos.html) ?

Comment: Thanks for ypur help, because it's a homework and and I'm told to install it using its source files. @Mat

Comment: Ok, but why use a version from somwhere in 2002 or 2003?

Answer (score 0):

As @Mat said , the version was old and the latest version of kerberos is fine.